# new.html.erb doesn't see the background color of style sheet

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

i make style sheet in assets, its name _loginstyle.css to adjust style of log_in page and sign_up page

```
<style>

body{
    background-color: #FFB6C1;
  }
  label{
    margin-left: 1000px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    color: black; 
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  input[type="email"]{
    margin-left: 1000px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  input[type="password"]{
    margin-left: 1000px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  input[type="submit"]{
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
</style>
```

and render it in new.html.erb
it show every thing except background color
any help please
i am beginner in ruby

this is new.html.erb

```
<body>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "loginstyle", media: "all" %>
<h1 style="margin-left: 1000px;" >Log in</h1>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the stylesheet link tag outside of your body.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: delete the style tag from the css file

Comment: it worked when i make !important and removed style tag thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

add !important to "background-color: #FFB6C1;" to be "background-color: #FFB6C1; !important"

Comment: it worked when i make !important and removed style tag thanks a lot